# Attempting to pull concatenated Q-urls, using data-type in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, nested

Will try and explain as concisely as I can.

Below is a dummy query based on one I'm attempting to edit.

I'm trying to return two different types which are pulled from the same table.

The first type of data is a numeric (a score from 1-10)

The next type of data is a both numbers and letters, used to complete a URL.

My problem is that the concat statement to return only null values. when I use the and statement to specify only URL data, the other column returns only null values.

Is there a way I can change this, to pull only one type of data in one column separate to the other?

Cheers

```
select 
concat("example.com/",rs.answer,"/415x380.png") as Q_URL,

  Ease_of_use.score as "Ease_Of_use"
  from customer_feedback c      
  left join response_data Ease_of_use on (Ease_of_booking_use.response_overall_id=c.id and Ease_of_use.data_type_id=1536)
  left join response_data rs on rs.customer_review_id=c.id
  join data_type dt on dt.id=rs.data_type_id
  where c.retailer_id in (678,1651)      
  and rs.answer is not null
  and dt.response_type="photo_URL"
  group by c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "I use the and statement to specify only URL data", but I would use isnull function to provide a default value for NULLS

concat("example.com/",isnull(rs.answer,"default value"),"/415x380.png")

rather than using rs.answer is not null

Comment: Sorry I'll try to clarify,

response_data holds many different types of values, which are categorized in the next table, data_type

In the query I've written "and dt.response_type="photo_URL" so that the concat photo url doesn't get populated with loads of other data which doesn't make sense in the URL. my problem is that I'm trying to return two different types of data types, but with my current query, without using an and statement, I return lots of bad URLs, however if I do, my query loses out on returning the other data type.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: No worries, figured it out in the end.. Thanks Ben!!